# Variables are not instantiated

Tags: python, django

```
def count_customers_per_period(self):
    if not self.request.GET.get('period'):
        period = self.request.GET['period']
        entry_date_production = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1)
        start_date = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__gte=entry_date_production).\
                first().user.date_joined
        end_date = CustomerProfile.objects.last().user.date_joined

        def start_end_period(period):
            start = start_date - datetime.timedelta(period)
            end = start + datetime.timedelta(period)

        if period == 'day':
            while start < end:
                array = np.array([])
                count = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__date=start_date).count()
                array = np.append(array, count)
                start_date += datetime.timedelta(1)
        elif period == 'week':
            start_end_period(7)
            while start < week:
                array = np.array([])
                count = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=[start, end])
                array = np.append(array, count)
                start = end + datetime.timedelta(1)
                end = start + datetime.timedelta(7)
        elif period == 'month':
            start_end_period(months=1)
            while start < end:
                array = np.array([])
                count = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=[start, end])
                array = np.append(array, count)
                start = end + datetime.timedelta(1)
                end = start + datetime.timedelta(months=1)
        elif period == 'year':
            start_end_period(years=1)
            while start < end:
                array = np.array([])
                count = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=[start, end])
                array = np.append(array, count)
                start = end + datetime.timedelta(1)
                end = start + datetime.timedelta(years=1)
    return array
```

In this method, I define `start_end_period()` function, because I need you use it multiple time.

**Questions :**

1. Is it normal that `start` and `end` are not instantiated whenever I call `start_end_period()` function?
2. Is it a good practice to put a function in a method as this way?

Comment: (1) You need to return `start` and `end` from `start_end_period`. (2) Defining local functions is a matter of style. Personally I think it's perfecly fine.

Comment: You define those variables inside of `start_end_period`, so they go out of scope as soon as you exit the function. You'll need to learn about variable scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` and `end` are local to the `start_end_period` and you don't return them, so yes it's normal that they aren't defined elsewhere. If you want them, you need to assign the returned values:

```
def start_end_period(period):
    start = start_date - datetime.timedelta(period)
    end = start + datetime.timedelta(period)
    return start, end
...

start, end = start_end_period(7)
```

I wouldn't say it was good practice to have a nested function like this. It's far more usual to have this as a separate method within the class, and call it explicitly with `self.start_end_period(whatever)`.

Comment: I know it is not recommended, but It is important for me... Thanks Daniel for your answer, I appreciate!

Comment: As I use it  only inside `count_customer_per_period()`, why should I define `start_end_date()` as a separate method within the class? For me, it is just logic to put it inside my method instead of defining as a single method() within my class.